# Compare multiple columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 date columns in a table, when created, last modified, and date an action was taken. I am trying to write a query that would compare the dates of all of these without having to write it out 3 different times.

Something like this is what I thought it would be and I have tried some variations but with no luck with my efforts and looking it up online(maybe because of the wording being to generic).

```
select * from table     
where (DateTimeInspected and DateTimeModified and DateTimeCreated) between '11/01/2012' and '11/01/2013'
```

Comment: Nope, as far as I know you have to type it all out.

Comment: You're looking for "all" of them to be between those dates or any of them? What RDBMS? Also if the column is `datetime` you probably don't want `between` anyway.

Comment: Using SQL Server, I want results if even one column matches and I do want to use between since I don't want to write out <= >= the dates the long way.

Comment: Well OK you might *want* to use `BETWEEN` but chances are that it doesn't do what you want! Because it is equivalent to `>= <=` it will include datetimes with the time component of midnight on the second date but not later times on the same date.

Answer (score 0):

By comparing dates you should be aware about the upper bound. If you write `<= "2013-11-20"` you will not get any data that has the date `2013-11-20`. Therefore you have to write `<= "2013-11-20 23:59:59"` or even better `< "2013-11-21"`.

Next you have to expand the where and use between for every column you want to check:
Therefore the SQL-query should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM table     
WHERE DateTimeInspected BETWEEN '11/01/2012' AND '11/01/2013'
    AND DateTimeModified BETWEEN '11/01/2012' AND '11/01/2013' 
    AND DateTimeCreated BETWEEN '11/01/2012' AND '11/01/2013'
```

Note: `column BETWEEN value1 AND value2` is equals to `column >= value1 AND column <= value2`

Comment: I am aware of that and did know what I was doing when I chose to use between. I was trying to determine if there was an easier way to do the query without having to write 3 different compares which seems to not be the case.

Comment: If you write `>= and <=` you will get the same result, but I think `between` is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like the following:

If you want one of them between the dates:

```
SELECT YourField
FROM TABLE
WHERE (DateTimeInspected BETWEEN '11/01/2012' AND '11/01/2013')
OR (DateTimeModified BETWEEN '11/01/2012' AND '11/01/2013')
OR (DateTimeCreated BETWEEN '11/01/2012' AND '11/01/2013')
```

Be careful with DateTime fields and BETWEEN though, because you do not specify a time in '11/01/2013', SQL will assume you mean '11/01/2013 00:00:00'. If the start and end dates are parameters you could add one day if necessary to solve this issue.

```
OR (DateTimeCreated BETWEEN '11/01/2012' AND DATEADD(day, 1, '11/01/2013') )
```

Comment: My main concern was with writing out 3 compares rather than one. I do know of the difference between between and >= <= and had it set up for me to do what I wanted.

Comment: Ok, clear. Then to answer your original question once more: unfortunately you can't do it in one statement.

Answer (score 0):

One way

```
SELECT *
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   (VALUES(DateTimeInspected),
                             (DateTimeModified),
                             (DateTimeCreated)) V(D)
               WHERE  V.D >= '20121101'
                      AND V.D < '20131101')
```

You should use an unambiguous `datetime` format such as `yyyymmdd` and `BETWEEN` probably doesn't do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question was about how to optimize checking boundaries for 3 dates at once.

In this case there is sense to create your own specific inline function to validate required conditions. It will allow you to reuse the functionality and have possibility to change it in a single place:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnDateTimeBetween](
@startDate datetime,
@endDate datetime,
@datetime1 datetime,
@datetime2 datetime,
@datetime3 datetime)
```

RETURNS bit

AS

BEGIN

```
DECLARE @result bit = 0

SELECT @result = 1
WHERE @datetime1 BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    AND @datetime2 BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
    AND @datetime3 BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate

RETURN @result
```

END

Then you'll be able to use it like:

```
SELECT dbo.fnDateTimeBetween('11/01/2012', '11/01/2013', '11/02/2012', '11/02/2012', '11/02/2012')
```